# Create Form in Cloudera

Tags: user-interface, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, flume-twitter

I am working in Cloudera ecosystem and as a beginner, I started by implementing flume twitter example and completed it successfully. Now, whenever I want to stream data from Twitter for different keywords I have to go into the configuration file of Twitter and edit it and then execute the flume agent by using the terminal.

I was thinking of a way to let the user open a form and enter keywords in it and execute the flume agent to get the data from Twitter rather than going to twitter configuration file each time. To do this I want to know is there any tool in Cloudera ecosystem to implement the idea that I have discussed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera Manager is the only interface that would allow Flume agent configurations, AFAIK.

Otherwise, you would have to make your own UI to accomplish something so specific.

If possible, you could [install a separate tool via a Parcel called Streamsets](https://www.cloudera.com/partners/solutions/streamsets.html), which is a more complete and programmable streaming tool, developed by some of the same people as Flume.